# how to migrate bacpac file of sql server to snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a bacpac file in azure storage account. I need to migrate that bacpac file to snowflake. I tried through Azure Data Factory but i cannot achieve it. Is there any way to migrate?

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by migrate a bacpac file? This  is just a file so I assume you aren't trying to load a file, as is, into Snowflake? Do you mean you want to import the schema/data from the file into Snowflake?

Comment: Hi @NickW 
Bacpac is nothing but backup. Its just a snapshot that can be used to move a database from one server to another (or to cloud) and archiving an existing database in an open format. I've taken this bacpac from sql server. now i want to load that to snowflake.

Comment: Yes, but it is used to move to a different Microsoft DB or Microsoft Cloud DB. While it is basically just a zip file it is not an open format in the sense that any other vendors use it. If you want to create a Snowflake Db from it you would need to restore the bacpac into a MS environment and then use the ETL tool of your source to move it to Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

According to the microsoft docs bacpac is only for Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance or SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export

Consequence: You can't import the bacpac file into Snowflake.

As far as I know you can also create a ".sql"-file of your database within SQL Server. A simple way to move your database/schemas/tables/views/ etc. to Snowflake is to create that .sql-file with all the DDL-statements and also DML-statements and copy the commands to your Snowflake worksheet.

On top of that you make sure that your data types are compatible with Snowflake.